# How to insert multiple IP addresses in a pg_hba.conf file via unix shell script?

Tags: postgresql, scripting, unix

I need to write some IP addresses to the pg_hba.conf file of my Postgresql, in order to allow remote access from those IP to my machine.

I have the following code in shell script to do that for a single IP address

```
#!/bin/bash

######## PostgreSQL Child Server Host or IP Address
serverhost=$1

######## PostgreSQL Child Server pg_hba.conf File Path
pghbapath=$2

######## Shell Script Command to write the data at the end of the    pg_hba.conf file
sed -i "$ a host    all all     $serverhost/32  md5" $pghbapath
```

An example command to execute the above bash script is

```
./reset_ip.sh 192.168.10.27 /root/Desktop/BashScripts/pg_hba.conf
```

The above is working fine, but I have a lot of IP addresses with me. So, instead of manually running the command each and every time for a different IP address, is there a command which can take multiple IP addresses at once and write them to the pg_hba.conf file in one go?

Edit - Thanks a lot for the answer Luuk. I tried it and it worked. Now, suppose if instead of having a text file to hold all the address, I want to write the multiple IP addresses separated by commas in the command line itself, somewhat like

```
./reset_ip.sh 192.168.10.27,192.168.10.28,192.168.10.29,192.168.10.30 /root/Desktop/BashScripts/pg_hba.conf
```

Is it possible? What I basically want is to be able to pass multiple values for a single variable via the command prompt.

Comment: How many times are you going to use this script? if an address is added to `pg_hba.conf` it is added, and does not need to be added again?

Comment: @Luuk What i mean is, I have around 200 IP addresses. Now instead of running the script separately 200 times for each of the IPs, is it possible to take all of them in one command and run it once?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file which holds all the addresses (1 at a line) you can do:

```
cat ipaddresses.txt | while read line; 
do 
  ./reset_ip.sh $line /root/Desktop/BashScripts/pg_hba.conf; 
done
```

or, with `gawk`:

```
gawk '{ system("./reset_ip.sh $1 /root/Desktop/BashScripts/pg_hba.conf") }' ipaddresses.txt
```